# Update permalinks

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I have added custom "folder" named Srpski to my permalink structure as you can see in .htaccess file below. So in WP Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks my custom permalink structure looks like this:

```
http://webdizajntest.com/poljoprivredni-fakultet/Srpski/%postname%/
```

This i working great when i add new post or page. It's displaying their permalinks with **Srpski** in url structure and that is what i need because of maintaining PageRank.

Problem is with old pages and posts. Their permalinks do not have this "directory" **Srpski** in url structure because they were saved without it.

I have a lot of pages and posts and i can't make them from the beginning, so my question is: **How can I update all existing page and posts permalinks in DB to have this structure with Srpski in URL?**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /poljoprivredni-fakultet/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /poljoprivredni-fakultet/Srpski/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: full urls are *not* stored in the DB. please try to explain better what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, my permalink structure is set like this: http://webdizajntest.com/poljoprivredni-fakultet/Srpski/%postname%/ so when i create new page or post, their permalink will be http://webdizajntest.com/poljoprivredni-fakultet/Srpski/new_post. Problem is that old posts and pages don't have Srpski in URL, and i need them to hav it

Comment: What exactly do you mean "old posts and pages don't have Srpski in URL"? they don't have now, they didn't have before or something else? If you changed your permalink structure like you said they should have Sprski in their url

Comment: Well that is the problem. I don't know why, but pages that I added before changing permalink structure now don't have Srpski in url. Example: http://webdizajntest.com/poljoprivredni-fakultet/misija-i-vizija/   but when i create new post, it has Srpski in url.

Answer (score 0):

You can try switching to basic permalink structure (the one with post id format) and then again choose custom permalink.

Or you can use following plugin to write desired URL for each page

[Custom Permalink Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your General options have to correct URL set.
(sorry that I can't comment this, not enough rep here)

If your htaccess file is correctly set on your server, everything should be working fine.

To move the url's try this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-moved-permanently/)

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is with old pages and posts. Their permalinks do not have this "directory" Srpski in url structure because they were saved without it.

I assume you mean links within the posts themselves. If so, you'll ideally want to edit the database entries. (There are plugins for that.) If not, some mod_rewrite rules should do the trick but your question isn't very clear.